# Jenkins Maven Plugin: Classloading Feature

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jibx

Good time!

Our team uses Maven. One of the project modules has a plugin (maven-jibx-plugin) that requires (for our use-case) a dependency on a proprietary jar:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jibx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jibx.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>main-schemas</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>schema-codegen</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaLocation>
                            ...
                        </schemaLocation>
                        <includeSchemas>
                            ...
                        </includeSchemas>
                        <customizations>
                            <customization>${basedir}/src/main/resources/customizations/customization.xml
                            </customization>
                        </customizations>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>bind</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>bind</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaBindingDirectory>
                            ${basedir}/src/main/resources/bindings
                        </schemaBindingDirectory>
                        <includeSchemaBindings>
                            <includeSchemaBinding>*.xml</includeSchemaBinding>
                        </includeSchemaBindings>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>${project.parent.groupId}</groupId>
                    <artifactId>proprietary-jar</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

The problem is when we build the project locally (and even from a command line on the remote machine where jenkins is istalled), everything builds successfully, but when our jenkins instance tries to build it - the build fails with such a message: "`Unable to find class 'class-name-from-the-proprietary-jar'`". This problem occurred loccally before we added the plugin dependency..

Seems like there is some feature of jenkins maven plugin that do no resolve the plugin dependencies or may be there are some well-known feature of the jenkins maven plugin classloading (JiBX loads proprietary classes with such a construct: `SchemaRootBase.class.getClassLoader().loadClass(cname)` So that specifing the dependency for the plugin should provide a knowledge for it about the required classes)... Can somebody, please, suggest the workaround?

**UPDATE:** 
it turned out that the jenkins instance's JAVA_HOME variable is set to `/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25`, but in my maven-compiler-plugin I have `<target>1.6</target>`. Could it be that the problem is in the 1.7 java version?

Comment: have you tried moving from maven build to freestyle build?

Comment: no I haven't. Actually our team has no access to jenkins - we can only check build statuses and see logs...

Comment: i dont think the target parameter has anything to do with it. i suspect youve indeed found an issue with the jenkins maven support, but the best way to verify would be to try switching the job to a freestyle job. can you at the very least try the exact same build on the jenkins machine running as the jenkins user? also, are you absolutely sure you and jenkins are using the same maven version ?

Comment: redai, thank you for the answer. Maven version is the same on my local machine and on the jenkins one, and we tried to build the project with nearly the same (instead of building all the project we used the project's module that fails) maven build command using the jenkins user (and from its workspace).

Comment: Is it possible that classloading politics changing while building the whole project or it's part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, finally I've found an answer! The problem is not actually in Jenkins, but rather in Maven itself.

***ATTENTION: the undergoing information is tested only for Maven 2.***

It turned out that when you have a **multimodule project** and several modules use **the same plugin** (with **different** dependencies), Maven would get dependencies set for **the first** plugin (I mean that the plugin is located in the first module, that Maven builds, with this plugin) and use them for other plugins not overriding the dependencies by the **local** values.

To clarify this lets have an example. Say there are two modules in the maven build - A and B:

```
<modules>
   <module>A</module>
   <module>B</module>
</modules>
```

and the module A has such the code in the *pom* file:

```
<plugin>
   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.c</groupId>
        <artifactId>D-module</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
   <artifactId>jibx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>${jibx.version}</version>
</plugin>
```

and the module B has such the code in the *pom* file:

```
    <plugin>
       <dependencies>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.c</groupId>
            <artifactId>F-module</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
         </dependency>
       </dependencies>
       <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
       <artifactId>jibx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>${jibx.version}</version>
    </plugin>
```

It turns out that when Maven builds the module B it will use the D-module dependency even though you have specified the F-module dependency.

In our project we made such a workaround: we moved the plugin declaration to the parent *pom* in a *pluginManagement* section and declared the D-module and F-module dependencies for the plugin (also removed these dependencies from the *local* modules). Ok, the code is rather ugly (having child dependencies in the parent *pom* file), but this works!

If somebody shared this issue and managed to overcome it, please, advice the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try `mvn clean install` in your workspace

Then you should have the same error every where. Also try and use the same command line Jenkins is using (if any)

Comment: Yes, we've tried that (please, see the question), but there are no errors. Errors are only raise when jenkins is building the project, that is why I guess there is a special thing about it's classloading...

Comment: It looks like that the jar filename completion on runtime is not being converted to what probably you want. Either the variable you have used is either spelled wrong and is not able to access what you want or it could be that the filename.jar value it has at runtime is not available in the directory specified

Comment: Archit Khosla, thank you for the interesting idea! I'll try to check it. It seems the the file's name is correctly converted since locally everything is correct. The file should be in the jenkins' maven repository, and according to the fact that before this JiBX feature has been committed no problems had been occurred, there are no troubles with repository access, but I'll check this.